# angular chained orderby not updating when running protractor tests in browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am currently facing an issue with angular's ng-repeat directive containing multiple, piped filters when running it during a Protractor test suite. Although I can see Protractor click the sort/toggle button, the list does not change as it should. I expect it to sort the list and only show some items when clicking special toggle buttons.

However, when I execute all the commands manually (in the same browser!), it works just fine!

Please find how I call Protractor:

```
element(by.id('customers_sort_id')).click();
browser.driver.sleep(500);
browser.waitForAngular();
expect(element.all(by.repeater('c in list.customers')).get(0).all(by.tagName('td')).first().getText()).toEqual('500');
```

I have built in the sleep() command as well as the waitForAngular() call just for debugging reasons, but they also change nothing.

These are two toggle buttons whether to display company customers, private customers, both types or none:

```
<label id="customers_show_company" ng-model="list.companyFilter.company" btn-checkbox>Companies</label>
<label id="customers_show_private" ng-model="list.companyFilter.private" btn-checkbox>Private</label>
```

This is one of the table header rows with sorting functionality:

```
<th id="customers_sort_id" ng-click="toggleSort('id')">
```

This is how the filter variable is set:

```
$scope.toggleSort = function(column) {
    if($scope.list.orderBy == column) {
        $scope.list.reverse = !$scope.list.reverse;
    }
    $scope.list.orderBy = column;
};
```

This is the table body:

```
<tr ng-repeat="c in list.customers | filter : list.companyFilter.visible | filter : list.searchFilter | orderBy : list.orderBy : list.reverse" ng-click="detailOn(c.id)">
```

Neither the orderBy nor the reverse filter do anything. Sorting it manually works as expected. When running Protractor tests, the sort functionality just doesn't work.

Does anyone have an idea why??
Thanks for any input!

Comment: How does it fail? Do you see the list sorted during the test run? How does the element with `id="customers_sort_id"` look?

Comment: Hi alecxe, thanks for your question. I have edited the question so it should now contain all relevant information.

Comment: have you tried longer sleep? Like 5000? I also suggest you to make a screenshot at failure